# Can you sign more than 1 Master Promissory Note Concurrently?

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school, funding

I am in the process of choosing a Master's program.  I have been approved for one program, but I'm still waiting to hear back from two other schools.  The school that approved me said that they need me to fill out my Master Promissory Note as soon as possible so my financial aid can be ready for my summer courses next month.  My only concern is that I may choose a different school if I get accepted into it.  If I'm not accepted into the other programs, however, I would like to have my financial aid taken care of so I can attend summer courses without any problems.

Can I sign the Promissory Note for my currently accepted program and then sign another Promissory Note for a different school if I am accepted?

Thank you and have a good day.

Comment: Why not just ask the financial aid office?  They've already accepted you, it's not like they're going to retract it.

Comment: @NateEldredge - Sorry I neglected to mention that.  I've tried asking the school I've been accepted to, but they didn't seem very confident with their response.  I called back another day and got a different F.A. specialist who gave me a completely different answer.  I called the second school and they don't have a large graduate program so their financial aid department  insists they only handle undergraduate F.A. inquiries and pend me back to the graduate enrollment advisor (who insists I need to talk to F.A. and forwards me back to their dept.)  I'm still awaiting a response from school #3.

Comment: This might depend on where you are and the local law. It might also depend on the specific meaning of "promissory note". But if it is a contract of some form, then it might not be possible. If you add detail it might be possible to answer.

Comment: This is a question about contract law, not academia.  I'm pretty sure the answer is "it depends on the terms of the contract."  Don't sign unless you are sure you agree to the terms.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the way this is done normally goes something like this:

- You apply to as many schools as you want.
- You hear back from them in a couple of months.
- You are told that you have until a specific date to accept the offer,
  which may be slightly different for all the schools you got accepted to.

This gives people a chance to evaluate (ideally) all their options before they agree to commit to a particular school. These deadlines are usually included in the acceptance documents you get in the mail, if they aren't listed online already in their admission timelines.

Best of luck!

Comment: I am not sure you answered the question. The OP is asking can he accept two offers?

Comment: I know this isn't really an answer, but it was too long to be a comment. I just wanted to share what I know that's all.